# Custom Connector UI default view

Tags: user-interface, powerbi, connector

Below is the snippet of simplified Custom Connector code.

```
section Simple;

[DataSource.Kind="Simple", Publish="Simple.Publish"]
shared Simple.Data = Value.ReplaceType(SimpleImpl,SimpleType);
Parameters = type [
    optional #"First parameter" = number,
    optional #"Second parameter"   = date,
    optional #"Third parameter"   = (type logical meta [
        Documentation.AllowedValues = {true,false}
    ])
];

SimpleType = type function (
    #"First parameter" as text,
    optional #"The Parameter" as Parameters
) 
as table meta [
    Documentation.LongDescription = "Simple",
    Documentation.Name = "Simple"
];
SimpleImpl = (
    #"Required parameter" as text,
    optional #"The Parameter" as record) =>
    let
```

It has one required and one optional parameter (which is a record) consisting of three “sub-parameters”.

[image]

The UI looks like:

Preferable would be – since second parameter is optional – that UI opens initially like below (not the one above):

In this case the user who is interested in providing values for First, Second, and Third parameter would click on the arrow.

[image]

Is it possible? Any help on how to set it up will be greatly appreciated!

I tried to look through documentation - there is no any mentioning of "Record" type parameters, least of default view setup.